# MVC CSS Default Colour

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've created a default MVC app, and want to change the background colour of the main form.  I go into the Site.css and change the following section:

```
body
{   
    background-color:Black;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:White;    
}
```

Then, when I view the Site.Master in design mode, it shows with a back background and white text.  However, when I subsequently run the app, it reverts to the default colours.  I can force the colour change by simply adding a style tag to the body:

```
<body style="background-color:Black">
```

And that works fine.  The CSS file seems to be wired up correctly:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong / missing?

Comment: So you're saying it works correctly on your IDE but defaults when deployed? Have you tried using an absolute path to your css?

Comment: have you tried clearing cache and refreshing the browser? css could be cached by your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the path to your stylesheet is correct. `../../` will only work when you're two folders deep relative to the root.

```
<link href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```